# Closed entries show in search results

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, search, entries

Using the search_results tags to display results I added a parameter like  when displaying channel entries, status="Open" to specifically show only "Open" entries, but it still shows Closed entries.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to include a bigger snippet of your template-code.

Answer (score 1):

I would try making the Open uncapped to status="open".

Maybe not the fix, but I have had weird issues around that.

Comment: Agreed, I've run into that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you are setting the status on the [search form tag itself](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/advanced.html#status), rather than on the results tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set status="Open" anywhere in your templates. ExpressionEngine already assumes you want "open" entries and will return "open" entries by default.